# How to apply a CSS file in the Google Apps Script project to an HTML file returned by doPost()?

Tags: html, css, forms, google-apps-script

I created a web form using Google Apps Script, where form visitors would see `result.html` after data submission. However, an external css file `css.html` in the same project of this `result.html` is not included in `result.html`.

I have five files in the same project of Google Apps Script:

1. **`index.html`** that produces the form
2. **`JavaScript.html`** that defines functions used in `index.html`
3. **`result.html`** that is presented after the form submission
4. **`css.html`** that defines the styles of both `index.html` and `result.html`
5. **`code.gs`** that shows the form by `doGet()`, and processes the submitted data and presents `result.html` by `doPost()`. `include()` defined in this file enables to input `JavaScript.html` and `css.html` into `index.html`

When I deploy the form, `index.html` is desirably presented since `<?!= include("css"); ?>` in the `index.html` successfully calls `css.html`. In the following picture, you can see that [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) font is used for the contents of the form.

[image]

However, `result.html` shown after data submission fails to include `css.html`, as demonstrated in the following figure. You can see the raw code (`<?!= include("css"); ?>`) appears and the Roboto is not used. Then, **what should I do to include `css.html` in `result.html` presented by the processes of `doPost()`?**

[image]

## index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include("css"); ?>
  </head>

  <body onload="addOptions()">   <!--Execute addOptions function immediately after a page has been loaded-->
    <form class="" action="<?!= getScriptUrl(); ?>" method="post" onSubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;">
      <div>
        <h1 id="Question">
          Choose either cheesecake or chocolate cake.
        </h1>
          <select id="dropdownList" name="cake" class="form-control"> 
          </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
  <?!= include('JavaScript') ?>
</html>
```

## code.gs

```javascript
var sheetID = "*****************************************";
var inventory_sheet = "Inventory";

function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getScriptUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  Logger.log(url);
  return url;
}

function doPost(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sh.appendRow([String(e.parameters.cake)]);

  //update Inventory
  var inventory = ss.getSheetByName(inventory_sheet);
  var row = inventory.createTextFinder(e.parameters.cake).findNext().getRow();
  var range = inventory.getRange(row, 2);
  var data = range.getValue();
  range.setValue(parseInt(data - 1))

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("result"); 
  
}

function getAvailableExps(){
  var inventory = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName(inventory_sheet);
  var data =  inventory.getRange(2, 1, 2, 2).getValues();
  var filtered = data.filter(arr =>  arr[1] > 0 || arr[1] != ''); //remove exp to array if quantity is 0 or empty
  return filtered;
}
```

## result.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base />
    <title>Thank you for your order!</title>
    <?!= include('css'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Don't forget what you've ordered!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

## css.html

```html
<style>
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

header {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

code, .codelike {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

a {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

option {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #3aab6d;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #a0ebc1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-submit {
  text-align: center; 
}

/* font-faces */

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOiCnqEu92Fr1Mu51QrEz4dL_nz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOiCnqEu92Fr1Mu51QrEzAdLw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TjASc0CsTKlA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TjASc6CsQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xGIzIFKw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xIIzI.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc0CsTKlA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc6CsQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic0CsTKlA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic6CsQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TLBCc0CsTKlA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TLBCc6CsQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxGIzIFKw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxIIzI.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfChc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfChc4EsA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap');

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your `result.html`, `css.html` is added using `<?!= include('css'); ?>` and your showing current image. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("result");
```

#### To:

```
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("result").evaluate();
```

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about `JavaScript.html` and whether your Google Apps Script works fine. So, this modification supposes that the other part of the script works fine. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [createTemplateFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createtemplatefromfilefilename)

Comment: Tanaike san, thank you for your solution! Your code greatly works!

Comment: @Carlos Luis Rivera Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.